# getContentAsPDF() SOQL has no rows

Tags: soql, pdf, getcontentaspdf

I have a problem. I need to get pdf and attach it to object.
I create object (and for test I execute query - it's ok), get ID and put it to page as parametr:

```
PageReference pdfPage = Page.ConsolidatedPDF;
pdfPage.getParameters().put('cInvoice', consId);
Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
```

then on controller of page ConsolidatedPDF:

```
consolidatedInvoiceTmp = [SELECT Id, Name FROM someObject__c WHERE Id =: consolidatedId];
```

consolidatedInvoiceTmp just empty but object with ID exist.

Can you help me?

```
public RecordAndPresentController(ApexPages.StandardSetController setController) {
    selectRecords = setController;
    selectRecords.setPageSize(2000);

    PageReference currentPage = ApexPages.currentPage();

    invoices = [
        SELECT id, Name, Status__c, Amount__c, Hours__c, RecordTypeId, Employee_Name__c, Period_Ending__c, Client__c,
                Client__r.AccountNumber
        FROM Invoice__c
        WHERE Id IN :((List<Invoice__c>)selectRecords.getSelected())
    ];

    //checkErrors();
}
public Invoice__c getConsolidatedInvoice() {
    String consolidatedRTId = getRecordTypeInvoiceId(CONSOLIDATED_RT);

    if (invoices.size() > 0 && !String.isEmpty(consolidatedRTId)) {
        Invoice__c cInvoice = new Invoice__c(RecordTypeId = consolidatedRTId, Hours__c = hours);
        insert cInvoice;

        for (Invoice__c inv : invoices) {
            inv.Parent__c = cInvoice.Id;
        }
        update invoices;

        return cInvoice;
    }

    return null;
}

public PageReference recordAction() {
    Invoice__c cInvoice = getConsolidatedInvoice();
    System.debug('straaangeeee ' + [select id, name FROM Invoice__c Where Id =: cInvoice.Id]);

    if (cInvoice != null) {
        attachPdfToInvoice(new List<Id> {cInvoice.Id});
    }
    return null;
}

public void attachPdfToInvoice(List<Id> cInvIdList) {

    List<Attachment> attachmentList = new List<Attachment>();

    for (Id consId : cInvIdList) {
        PageReference pdfPage = Page.ConsolidatedPDF;
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('cInvoice', consId);
        Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();

        attachmentList.add(new Attachment(parentId = consId, name = 'test' + '.pdf', body = pdfBlob));
    }
    insert attachmentList;
}
```

And controller for ConsolidatedPDF page:

```
public String consolidatedId { get; set; }

public TestPDFController() {
    consolidatedId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cInvoice');
    getDataForPDFInvoice();
}

public void getDataForPDFInvoice() {
    List<Invoice__c> detailedInvoices;
    List<Invoice__c> consolidatedInvoiceTmp;
    consolidatedInvoiceTmp = new List<Invoice__c>();
    if (!String.isEmpty(consolidatedId)) {
        System.Debug('Id ' + consolidatedId);
        consolidatedInvoiceTmp = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Invoice__c WHERE Id =: consolidatedId];

        System.Debug('result ' + consolidatedInvoiceTmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if you are querying right object.

Comment: Yes, object is right. Also if this ID put in parametrs of SOQL and start the process once again - I got objects (i.e. use Id from previously iteration).

Comment: are you using a standard controller?

Comment: No, I use custom controller
But I use a standard controller on page where I set param to "ConsolidatedPDF" page

Comment: Can you share your controller code? It appears you're using the wrong parameter to set the `consolidatedId`

Comment: @FernandoGavinho please see code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PageReference pdfPage = Page.ConsolidatedPDF;
pdfPage.getParameters().put('Id', consId);
Blob pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Sharat. But it not helps

Comment: Please share your controller code.

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar please see code